# One div fixed height and another div remaining vertical space to make it 100% of window height

Tags: html, height, width

In a container div I have two divs inside it. Div-A is fixed height and Div-B should fill the remaining space to make it 100% of brower's window:

```
+------------------------+ #container
| +--------------------+ |
| |       Div-A        | |
| |    (height:60px)   | |
| +--------------------+ |
| +--------+ +---------+ |
| |        | |         | |
| |        | |         | |
| |  Div-B | | Div-C   | |
| |w: 25px | | W: ??   | |
| |H: ??   | | H: ??   | |
| |        | |         | |
| +--------+ +---------+ |
+------------------------+
```

I have following style:

```
body, html{
min-height: 100%;
}

#container{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 2px;
 bottom: 2px;
 right: 2px;
 }
#div-a{
 height: 60px;
 }
#div-b{
 float: left;
 min-height: 100%;
 width: 25px;
 margin-bottom: 2px;
 background: url('img.png') 0 0;
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
 }
#div-c{
 position: relative;
 margin: 2px 2px 2px 25px;
 min-height: 100%;
 }
```

But it is not working as expected. Div-C is overlapping container div as the left margin of Div-C is 25px (i.e. width of Div-C is becoming 25px+100%) and height of Div-A is 60px (i.e. height of Div-C is becoming 60px+100%). So right and bottom margin of Div-C are not creating due to overlapping.

```
+------------------------+ #container
| +--------------------+ |
| |       Div-A        | |
| |    (height:60px)   | |
| +--------------------+ |
| +--------+ +-----------+ 
| |        | |           |
| |        | |           |
| |  Div-B | | Div-C     |
| |w: 25px | | W: ??     |
| |H: ??   | | H: ??     |
| |        | |           |
| +--------+ |           |
+------------+-----------+
```

What is the wrong in this code?

Comment: can u provide me your html code also

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to this apply this css it matching your requirement

```
body, html {
    min-height: 100%;
}
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 0px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
#div-a {
    height: 16%;
    width: 96%;
    float: left;
    margin: 2%;
    background: #ddd888;
}
#div-b {
    float: left;
    min-height: 78%;
    width: 46%;
    margin: 0% 2% 2% 2%;
    background: #bbb;
}
#div-c {
    float: left;
    min-height: 78%;
    width: 48%;
    margin: 0% 2% 2% 0%;
    background: #000;
}
```

and html its help full for you

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="div-a"></div>
  <div id="div-b"></div>
  <div id="div-c"></div>
</div>
```